My sda partitions got re-ordered after recovered windows,any future prob in ubuntu?
i'm new to linux
after i recoverd my windows all sda partitions got re-ordered,,for example ubuntu partitions
was sda1--/boot/efi    sda2--/root    sda3--/home,,
now sda7--/boot/efi    sda6--/root    sda5--/home.
ubnutu still works normally,i opened timeshift just to see which partitoins will be targeted if i want to do a restore,it targeted the new one's.
my questions is there any future prob?
i used "Hiren's BootCD PE" and "EaseUS Todo" for recovering windows 11...
thanks

you may find this explanation from stackexchange answers your question. The only time this might become relevant is if you insist on referring to a block device by its allocated designator rather than the UUID (in fstab for example)

We won't know as you've provided few specifics; we don't know what Ubuntu product/release you're using, and more importantly how you reference your partitions in the disk.. If you use the sda9 (block device ref) then you'll have problems, if however you reference partition using UUID then as long as UUID wasn't changed it'll still work.

the system still working good , i'm using ubuntu 24.04, and ubuntu cinnamon 24.04, and yes i use UUID as ref. thx alot
